# C++: target window does not react to SendMessageCallbackA()

Tags: c++, winapi, events, input, key

I want to simulate a key press in a window which I know the handle of. I tried:

```cpp
SendMessageCallbackA(window, WM_KEYDOWN, 0x41, 1, [](HWND _1, UINT _2, ULONG_PTR _3, LRESULT _4) {}, 0);
// Wait
SendMessageCallbackA(window, WM_KEYUP, 0x41, 1 | 1 << 30 | 1 << 31, [](HWND _1, UINT _2, ULONG_PTR _3, LRESULT _4) {}, 0);
```

In this case I'm trying to send `A`. I also tried different `wParam` and `lParam`, but no one works. If I send `WM_CLOSE`, the window reacts to it. I guess I'm simulating a key wrong, or the window gets its input from somewhere else...

If I use `SendInput()` for the task, it works. Why wouldn't `SendMessageCallbackA()` work? I was looking for different / faster ways of sending input to the window

## Edit

I tried with `WM_CHAR` too, the following cases (not all at once):

```cpp
// Pressing
SendMessageCallbackA(window, WM_CHAR, 'A', 1 << 30, [](HWND _1, UINT _2, ULONG_PTR _3, LRESULT _4) {}, 0);
SendMessageCallbackA(window, WM_CHAR, 'A', 1 | 1 << 30, [](HWND _1, UINT _2, ULONG_PTR _3, LRESULT _4) {}, 0);

// Releasing
SendMessageCallbackA(window, WM_CHAR, 'A', 1 << 31, [](HWND _1, UINT _2, ULONG_PTR _3, LRESULT _4) {}, 0);
SendMessageCallbackA(window, WM_CHAR, 'A', 1 | 1 << 31, [](HWND _1, UINT _2, ULONG_PTR _3, LRESULT _4) {}, 0);
```

Tried with `'a'` rather than `'A'` too

Comment: Maybe the window is actually listening for WM_CHAR?

Comment: @user253751, interesting remark. Unfortunately it didn't work. I will update my question with new details

Comment: [You can't simulate keyboard input with PostMessage](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20050530-11/?p=35513).

Comment: @IInspectable, what you're saying make sense, but here's the thing: the application does respond faster to the real keyboard. If I run the app at a low fps, seems like it still register the key at the right time, so I guess the key was appended to the event queue and the appliaction doesn't do an additional check. I'm expecting to send input faster or at the same pace compared to real one. Not even gonna mention that if I virtually release the key too fast, the app won't even catch it with `SendInput()`

Comment: An application that responds to input *events* will always observe state changes that result from a call to `SendInput`, even when the API is used to inject multiple input events in a single call (which is how it should be used anyway). If the target application misses input, then it doesn't respond to input events, but rather samples the keyboard state. This is as common as it is annoying. And there's nothing you can do. You cannot fix a broken application from the outside. You can only lower the probability for the breakage to surface.

Comment: @IInspectable, "samples the keyboard state"? So the only single way to speed up the input is to fake the sampling such as hooking the getter function? Also, since it is so precise, maybe it is a hardware thing? I have kernel control, so basically I'm able to try all sorts of dirty tricks if it's a must